# Why not always use the ADAM optimization technique?

Tags: neural-network, optimization

It seems the [Adaptive Moment Estimation (Adam)](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/) optimizer nearly always works better (faster and more reliably reaching a global minimum) when minimising the cost function in training neural nets.

Why not always use Adam? Why even bother using RMSProp or momentum optimizers?

Comment: I don't believe there is any strict, formalized way to support either statement. It's all purely empirical, as error surface is unknown. As a rule of thumb, and purely from m experience, ADAM does well where others fail (instance segmentation), although not without drawbacks (convergence is not monotone)

Comment: Adam is faster to converge. SGD is slower but generalizes better. So at the end it all depends on your particular circumstances.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem would seem relevant.  Different optimization algorithms work better on different problems, and there is no universally superior one.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Here](https://shaoanlu.wordpress.com/2017/05/29/sgd-all-which-one-is-the-best-optimizer-dogs-vs-cats-toy-experiment/)’s a blog post reviewing an article claiming SGD is a better generalized adapter than ADAM.

There is often a value to using more than one method (an ensemble), because every method has a weakness.

Answer (score 19):

You should also take a look at [this](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/) post comparing different gradient descent optimizers. As you can see below Adam is clearly not the best optimizer for some tasks as many converge better.

Comment: Just for the record: In the linked article they mention some of the flaws of ADAM and  present AMSGrad as a solution. However, they conclude that whether AMSGrad outperform ADAM in practices is (at the time of writing) non-conclusive.

Comment: this link appears to be offline

Comment: @OuttaSpaceTime the link works for me! (not sure if fixed or edited)

Comment: @tturbo you are right! now it's working. Thanks for pointing this out